# Cannot implicitly convert type void to microsoft.win32.registrykey

Tags: c#, registry

Error: cannot implicitly convert type void to microsoft.win32.registrykey

Code:

```
using Microsft.Win32;
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Sofware",true).DeleteSubKey("TEST");
```

But for some reason this code works:

```
using Microsft.Win32;
RegistryKey key1 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Sofware", true).CreateSubKey("TEST");
```

Comment: Return type of `DeleteSubkey()` is `void`, it's not gonna give you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the signature of `DeleteSubKey` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.deletesubkey)
It says it is `void`, hence it returns nothing and cannot be assigned to `RegistryKey`. Call the function without using its return value